# Issues in socket programming between Android and Java server

Tags: java, android, sockets

The problem I'm getting is that I'm able to connect properly, but the damned connection just won't close! What must I do?

**Server Side :**

*Listen.java*

```
package com.example.ServerSide;


import java.net.ServerSocket;

public class Listen extends servVars {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("HOSTED");
            hostAt = new ServerSocket(2051);
            conDev = hostAt.accept();
            System.out.println(conDev.getInetAddress()+":"+conDev.getPort());
            for(;;) {
                System.out.print(".");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                if(conDev.isClosed())
                    break;
            }
        } catch(Exception E) {

        }
    }

}
```

*servVars.java*

```
package com.example.ServerSide;

import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class servVars {
    static ServerSocket hostAt;
    static Socket conDev;
}
```

**Client Side :**

*Connect_to_server.java*

```
package com.example.clientside;

import java.net.Socket;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Connect_to_server extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText IP_field;
    private EditText port_field;
    private String IP;
    private String portStr;
    private int port;
    public static Socket conn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.connect_to_server);
        IP_field = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.IP_field);
        port_field = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.port_field);
        Button connect = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.connect_button);
        connect.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.connect_to_server, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        IP = IP_field.getText().toString();
        portStr = port_field.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Trying to connect to "+IP+":"+portStr,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            port = Integer.parseInt(portStr);
            conn = new Socket(IP, port);
            Intent landing = new Intent(this, Landing.class);
            startActivity(landing);
        } catch(Exception E) {
            Intent failure = new Intent(this, ConnectFail.class);
            failure.putExtra("ctsException", E.toString());
            startActivity(failure);
        }
    }

}
```

*Landing.java*

```
package com.example.clientside;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Landing extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.landing);
        Button disconnect = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.disconnect_button);
        disconnect.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.landing, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            Connect_to_server.conn.close();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Disconnected!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch(Exception E) {}
    }

}
```

I didn't post the layouts and ConnectFail.java as it wouldn't be necessary, I think.

Edit : I'm guessing that this has something to do with the Socket and ServerSocket being static. But, I have no clue how to make them non-static and still make the program run!

Answer (score 0):

`isClosed()` tells you whether *you* have closed the *socket.* It doesn't tell you anything about the state of the *connection.* If the peer closes the socket you will get an EOF indication when reading:

- `read()` returns -1
- `readLine()` returns null
- `readXXX()` throws `EOFException` for any other XXX.

As your server isn't reading anything from the client, it cannot possibly discover when the client has closed the connection.

Comment: But, the connection between the Client and the Server is persistent, right? How do I send a disconnect command from the Client to the Server?

Comment: @user Connections persist until one of the peers closes. The client is closing, but the sever isn't doing anything that would detect that. So from the server's point of view the connection never appears to be closed, which is the problem you have. The server has to *read.* In fact I am wondering what is the point of this system when there is no apparent network I/O at all.

Comment: Well, this is just a minor part of the system. It's just my style of making systems. :P

But, I finally dealt with the problem. I figured that if the Server won't detect the Client's disconnection, I would make the Client keep sending "I'm Alive" packets to the Server every few seconds, running in a parallel thread, and when the packets stop coming, the Server figures that the Client ain't connected no more. Thanks for your help, though! ^_^